# I have a piece of code i.e a method with try and catch block. The catch block catches the exception how can I write the failure junit for it?

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, junit5

Below is the piece of code. Now already the exception is caught. How can I write the negative test for the same? To make sure code enters in catch block?

```
public ThirdPartyResponse load(ThirdPartyRequestContext context) {

    ThirdPartyResponse thirdPartyResponse = new ThirdPartyResponse();
    try
    {
        thirdPartyResponse.setData(getData(context));
    }catch (Exception e)
    {
        LOGGER.error("Error executing {}", context.getEndpoint(), e);
        thirdPartyResponse.setData(Collections.emptyList());
        thirdPartyResponse.setErrorMessage(e.getMessage());
    }
    return thirdPartyResponse;
}
```

Comment: You could check if the ErrorMessage is empty or not.

Comment: @SofoGial But in that case I need to get error message first right? Could u be a little more specific?

Comment: You need to assert that `thirdPartyResponse.getErrorMessage()` is not empty in your test.

Comment: Are you using any mocking libraries like mockito?

Comment: @MaciejKowalski Yes using mockito

Answer (score 1):

You can assert that error message is not null for the thirdPartyResponse object that's returned from your method:

```
assertNotNull(thirdPartyResponse.getErrorMessage());
```

import statement:

```
import static org.junit.Assert.assertNotNull;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// mock context so that getData(context) throws exception with message "foo"
...
ThirdPartyResponse response = load(context);
assertThat(response.getMessage(), is("foo"));
```

Comment: getData is private method.

Comment: That's why I said mock context. E.g. if `getData(context)` contains the line `context.getSession()`, have `context.getSession()` throw an exception with message "foo". This will propagate to the catch block in load.

Answer (score 0):

1st of all , don't try to catch main "`Exception`" in catch as it will catch all kind of exception which you may not even want to catch. Next, if you want to write test case for that you need to use `Mockito` for performing that negative test, you need to write something like this

```
Mockito.when(some_method(anyparam())).thenThrow(new YourCustomException("error message"));
```

probably you may need to mock inside `getData()` method.

Answer (score 0):

As you are using mockito try following:

**1)** Alter the `load` method so that the `thirdPartyResponse` is a protected method call:

```
public ThirdPartyResponse load(ThirdPartyRequestContext context) {

    ThirdPartyResponse thirdPartyResponse = createThirdPartyResponse();
```

**2)** Put creation of that object inside the `createThirdPartyResponse()`:

```
protected ThirdPartyResponse createThirdPartyResponse(){
   return new ThirdPartyResponse(); 
}
```

**3)** Spy on the SUT and mock the  `createThirdPartyResponse` method:

```
public class ClassUnderTest{

   @Spy 
   ClassUnderTest classUnderTestSpy;

   @Spy
   ThirdPartyResponse thirdPartyResponseSpy;

   @BeforeClass
   public void init(){
      MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
   }

   public void expectExceptionOnLoad(){
      // Arrange
      Mockito.doThrow(new Exception()).when(thirdPartyResponseMock.setData(Mockito.any(Object.class));

     Mockito.doReturn(thirdPartyResponseSpy).when(classUnderTestSpy).createThirdPartyResponse();

       // Act
       classUnderTestSpy.load(context);

       // Assert
       assertNotNull(thirdPartyResponseSpy.getErrorMessage());
   }
}
```

PS. you need to replace the `Mockito.any(Object.class)` with a adequate class